# Dired: How to open file with ace-window while keeping focus on dired buffer?

Tags: dired, window, ace-window, display-buffer

I have this Elisp code that allows me to use ace-window to open a file in a selected window from Dired:

```lisp
  (defun find-file-dired-ace-window ()
    "Use ace window to select a window for opening a file from dired."
    (interactive)
    (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
      (if (> (length (aw-window-list)) 1)
          (aw-select "" (lambda (window)
                          (aw-switch-to-window window)
                          (find-file file)))
    (find-file-other-window file))))
```

This works well, however I find it annoying that the focus switches to the newly opened buffer. I would like the focus to stay in the Dired buffer.

I have thought to use `save-window-excursion` for this, however now the file does not get opened at all, so it is totally useless:

```lisp
  (defun save-excursion-dired-ace-window ()
    "Use ace window to select a window for opening a file from dired."
    (interactive)
    (save-window-excursion
      (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
        (if (> (length (aw-window-list)) 1)
            (aw-select "" (lambda (window)
                            (aw-switch-to-window window)
                            (find-file file)))
          (find-file-other-window file)))))
```

How can I can get the desired behavior?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `find-file` (or `find-file-other-window`).

Use **`find-file-noselect`** to obtain a buffer visiting the file. Then use `display-buffer-pop-up-window` to display it in another window.

There are other buffer-display functions you can use, if you want to show it in some existing window. `C-h f display-buffer` tells you about them.

Dunno what `aw-switch-to-window` does. If that selects the window then maybe you don't want to do that. But the overall point is to use **`display-buffer`** (or one of its sidekicks), not `find-file` (or one of its sidekicks).  And use **`find-file-noselect`** to get you the file-visiting buffer to display.

```lisp
(defun find-file-dired-ace-window ()
    "Use ace window to select a window for opening a file from dired."
    (interactive)
    (let* ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit))
           (buf  (find-file-noselect file)))
      (if (> (length (aw-window-list)) 1)
             (aw-select "" (lambda (window)
                             (aw-switch-to-window window)
                             (display-buffer buf)
                             buf))
       (display-buffer-pop-up-window buf nil)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Whenever I select a buffer with this command I get the error "Invalid buffer", and I get switched to the selected window without the new buffer being opened.

Comment: I had a typo: `file` instead of `buf` was passed to `display-buffer`. And maybe your `aw-select` expects its function arg to return a buffer (like `find-file` does). Try what I have now. If that doesn't help, then at least see if the other branch works, i.e., when `aw-window-list` returns less than 2.

Answer (score 0):

This may be hacky but it works! I save the dired buffer at the beginning and then switch back to it right at the end.

```
 (defun find-file-dired-ace-window ()
    "Use ace window to select a window for opening a file from dired."
    (interactive)
    (let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit))
          (dired-buf (current-buffer)))
      (if (> (length (aw-window-list)) 1)
          (progn
            (aw-select "" (lambda (window)
                            (aw-switch-to-window window)
                            (find-file file)))
            (let ((dired-window (get-buffer-window dired-buf)))
              (when dired-window
                (select-window dired-window))))
    (find-file-other-window file))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is  ...

1. Declare your intention ...
2. Do the command
3. Pick the window
4. Profit!

It is not "natural".  May be it is just a question of getting  used to this sort of workflow.

---

1. Copy below snippet to `~/scratch.el`

```lisp
(package-initialize)

(require 'ace-window)

(ace-window-display-mode 1)

(define-key ctl-x-4-map "5" 'ace-window-prefix)

(defun ace-window-prefix ()
  "See `other-window-prefix."
  (interactive)
  (display-buffer-override-next-command
   (lambda (buffer _alist)
     "No clue what is happening here.  May require further tuning."
     (cons (let ((aw-dispatch-when-more-than 1)
         (aw-dispatch-always nil))
         (aw-select nil))
       'reuse))
   ;; Switch to window you started with
   (lambda (oldw neww)
     (unless (eq oldw neww)
       (select-window oldw)))
   "[ace-window]")
  (message "Display next command buffer in an existing window ..."))
```

2. Quit Emacs.  Restart with `emacs -Q`.
3. `C-x 4 C-f ~/scratch.el` and do `M-x eval-buffer RET`
4. `C-x 4 C-f RET`.  This will open your Home directory, and place the cursor on the  first file or dir there.
5. Do `C-x 4 5 RET`.

   **(Take care that there is no key presses between `C-x 4 5` and `RET`.  This is important.)**
6. `ace-window` will prompt you for the window to select.  Select the window.
7. The `RET`-ed file will be opened in the selected window.
8. .... and you will be in whatever window you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach ... But before that, some remarks upfront.

---

The key function call you are looking for is `aw-flip-window`.

---

1. The workflow with `o` (= `my-aw-dired-find-file-other-window-noselect`, which overrides the vanilla `dired-find-file-other-window`) is fairly intuitive.

   You pick the window, instead of `Emacs` picking some "random" window for you.  This is great!
2. The workflow with `C-x 4 C-f`  (= `my-aw-find-file-other-window-noselect`, which overrides the vanilla `find-file-other-window`) is:

   - Select the window
   - Select the file

   Which again is quite intuitive.  Great!

In both the workflows, the clutter is in the glue code.

---

1. Copy the below snippet to `~/scratch-1.el`

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

(require 'ace-window)

(defmacro ace-window-do-other-window-noselect (fn1 fn2 &rest body)
  `(defun ,(intern (format "my-aw-%s-noselect" (symbol-name fn1))) ()
     (interactive)
     (let ((value (progn ,@body))
       (current-window (selected-window)))
       (cond
    ((> (length (aw-window-list)) 2)
     (aw-switch-to-window (aw-select nil))
     (cond
      ((null ',body)
       (call-interactively ',fn2))
      (t (funcall ',fn2 value))))
    (t (call-interactively ',fn1)))
       (unless (eq current-window (selected-window))
     (aw-flip-window)))))

(require 'dired)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "o")
        (ace-window-do-other-window-noselect
         dired-find-file-other-window
         find-file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 4 C-f")
        (ace-window-do-other-window-noselect
         find-file-other-window
         find-file))
```

2. Quit `Emacs` with `C-x C-c`, and restart with `emacs -Q`.
3. `C-x C-f ~/scratch-1.el`, and do `M-x eval-buffer`.
4. `C-x 4 C-f ~/ RET`.  This will open your Home directory.  Your cursor will still be in `~/scratch-1.el` buffer.

   Note that the `C-x 4 C-f` used here is a redefined one.
5. `C-x o`, and switch to `dired` buffer, that is displaying your  `Home` dir.
6. The cursor is on the first file / dir in your `Home` dir. Press `o`.  It will open the chosen file / dir in another window.
7. There is no magic so far.  There are only 2 windows, and there is no confusion about what the other window is.
8. `C-x 3`.  There are 3 windows, and the same `dired` buffer is displayed in 2 different windows.
9. Do a couple of `C-n`s and move to some other file/dir.  This is so that you have variety of buffers.  Press `o`. `ace-window` will prompt you for a window.  Input the window choice.
10. Note that the file / dir on which you pressed `o`, opened in window of your choosing, and you are still in the same window `dired` window you started with.
11. Do a `C-x 4 C-f`. `ace-window` will prompt you for a window.  Input the window choice.
12. Now `find-file` will prompt you for the file name.  Input, say `~/scratch-1.el`.
13. Note that the `~/scratch-1.el` is in opened in selected window, and you are still in the same window you started with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the TLDR version of my response here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72468/31220.

Install the below snippet.  The snippet overrides/redefines `o` in `dired-mode-map`, in such a way that ***you get to pick*** what the other window is.  FWIW, `o` in `dired-mode-map` maps to `dired-find-file-other-window`.   You can see that this is the `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` version of whatever you see in that response.

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)

(require 'ace-window)
(require 'dired)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "o")
            (defun my-aw-dired-find-file-other-window-noselect ()
              (interactive)
              (let ((value (dired-get-file-for-visit))
                    (current-window (selected-window)))
                (cond
                 ((> (length (aw-window-list)) 2)
                  (aw-switch-to-window (aw-select nil))
                  (funcall 'find-file value))
                 (t (call-interactively 'dired-find-file-other-window)))
                (unless (eq current-window (selected-window))
                  (aw-flip-window)))))
```